# Compare lists with a function and no empty cells between

Tags: excel

I want to compare 2 lists in excel. Each is on a seperate Worksheet. The output need to be a list like in Difference.

I can use Excel only without VBA. Someone an idea how to solve this :S
My problem is that i dont know how get Peter and Fabienne without the empty cell between.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `FILTER()` formula if you have `Excel-365`

```
C7=FILTER(A2:A4,D2:D4<>A2:A4)
D7=FILTER(B2:B4,E2:E4<>B2:B4)
```

You just need to add sheet reference to compare with `Sheet2` like

```
=FILTER(A2:A4,Sheet2!D2:D4<>A2:A4)
```

[image]

Comment: I forgot to say that i havent Office365. I use 2016